Excel - how to handle custom timestamp format
I have some measurement data from a datalogging software, saved as CSV, and one column contains time stamps like this:
12.04.2024 15:11:32:684
12.04.2024 15:11:35:752

The format of this is:
dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss:fff

where fff is milliseconds.
Opening the CSV file works fine in Excel. The question is, how can I make MS Excel understand this timestamp format, and then calculate the elapsed time (time difference) between start and each datalogging entry?
The custom cell format does not seem to accept "hh:mm:ss:000" (000 for fractions of second). After replacing the last colon (:) with a dot (.) I can format it as "hh:mm:ss.000", but calculating the elapsed time still doesn't work, it seems to produce garbage results.

Please edit your question to show the formula you are using and your so-called garbage results.

It would be best to post online a small example spreadsheet (OneDrive, Dropbox etc).

You may be getting garbage results because hours through seconds are based on 60 units but a millisecond is one thousandth of a second. You might need to convert to a common unit (e.g., milliseconds) to perform a calculation and then reconvert to the multiple units.

What format would you like the result to be calculated in?

For Excel this time stamp is a text. To convert it into number you should change the third colon to your current decimal separator, probably .. You can use a formula:
=--SUBSTITUTE(A1,":",".",3)

Use , instead of . if you use , as decimal separator.
Then use custom format if you need to see date and time.
dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss.000

To perform calculations, you can use unformatted numbers. Format only the final result.

I use comma as decimal separator.
